# Colors in Tree View Odoo 9 ERROR

Tags: odoo, odoo-9

Good Day!,
I've trying to Migrate my Odoo8 to 9 But I have an error in One2Many Grid Colors
here's my code

```
                            <group>
                            <data>
                                <field name="employee_documents" string ="">
                                    <tree colors = "red:expired=='EXP'">
                                        <field name="document"/>
                                        <field name="document_number"/>
                                        <field name="date_issued"/>
                                        <field name="date_expiry"/>
                                        <field name="issuing_authority"/>
                                        <field name="place_ofissue"/>
                                        <field name="expired" />
                                    </tree>                                 
                                </field>
                            </data>
                        </group>
```

and I having an Error

> Uncaught Error: QWeb2 - template['ListView.rows']: Runtime Error: Error: QWeb2 - template['ListView.row']: Runtime Error: Error: NameError: name 'expired' is not defined

I found out the colors attribute is causing the error because when I remove it my grid is not causing an Error,

Is there new way in Odoo 9 to do this thanks

Answer (score 0):

This is the correct way to add color attribute in treeview. You should check your `.py` file where you have defined the field `expired`.
From the error it is clear that this error is related to the definition of the field, not due to the color attribute. At runtime your filed `expired` is not located. That is why you are getting this error.

Comment: My Grid is allow to add and edit is there an effect in the new Odoo 9 and I have following field expired in the .py file

Comment: Can you please add a snapshot of your .py file, where you have defined field "expired"

Comment: @VikashMishra I am havind the same problem, trying to modify a one2many treeview color from a char field named `color`, but I get `Error: NameError: name 'color' is not defined`. Tried with both decoration and color, the same results. `decoration-danger="color=='red'"`. I even made the field color visible in the tree

Comment: The field is computed, tried on another field and it worked. Need to know if it is possible to make the computed field works as well

Answer (score 0):

For v9, colors are gone - replaced by the following decorators:

```
decoration-bf - shows the line in BOLD

decoration-it - shows the line in ITALICS

decoration-danger - shows the line in LIGHT RED

decoration-info - shows the line in LIGHT BLUE

decoration-muted - shows the line in LIGHT GRAY

decoration-primary - shows the line in LIGHT PURPLE

decoration-success - shows the line in LIGHT GREEN

decoration-warning - shows the line in LIGHT BROWN
```

The formatting is dependent on the bootstrap style, and these can be combined (the colors look better when shown bold)

https://www.odoo.com/fr_FR/forum/aide-1/question/set-color-in-tree-view-based-on-task-stage-94556

Answer (score 0):

From Odoo9 onward colour attribute as like odoo8 version is being depricated.
In odoo8 we can keep color for tree view rows like this

`<tree string="tree_view_BT" colors="red:state == 'inact'">`

This is being depricated in odoo9. In odoo9 you can only use a set of defined colors only.

> In odoo9, tree views can take supplementary attributes to further customize their behavior as follows:
>
> **decoration-{$name} :** This attribute allows changing the style of a row's text based on the corresponding record's attributes.

*{$name}* can be replaced with *bf* for having font weight as bold.

For example **decoration-bf="condition("state=='open'")"**

For *italics* keep as **decoration-it="condition"**

Odoo9 support only bootstrap contextual colors such as

> bootstrap contextual colors (danger, info, muted, primary, success or
>   warning).
>   [Bootstrap contextual colors](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#available-variations)

decoration-danger='condition' for **Red**

decoration-info='condition' for **Blue**

decoration-muted='condition' for **Grey**

decoration-primary='condition' for **Purple**

decoration-success='condition' for **Green**

decoration-warning='condition' for **Orange**

Answer (score -1):

Actually colors are deprecated from V9. we can use like this

Decoration-danger as red and decoration-info as blue.

Comment: <tree decoration-danger="total_days&gt;10" decoration-info="total_days&lt;10">